# Fabric js canvas border affects mouse offset

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Using Fabric JS, I have a 100px border as an inline style for my canvas

```
<canvas id='c' style = 'border: solid red 100px;'></canvas>
```

This is causing issues with selecting objects as the mouse position seems to be offset by the border width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/solex16/uzzsgh2p/5/)**

I have tried to fix  the issue using

```
obj.setCoords();
```

and

```
canvas.calcOffset();
```

with no joy?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58asqazg/). FabricJs generates 2 canvases and they are not placed coreectly inside `.canvas-container` class

```
#c{
    border: 100px solid #AAA;
}
.upper-canvas{
    top: 100px !important;
    left: 100px !important;
}
```